# Catalan numbers in programming

Tags: soft-question, catalan-numbers

I've heard that Catalan numbers are nowadays used in many applications. But how are they really helpful in programming?

Comment: It would be useful to know where you heard this. I suspect that the person did not mean that it is useful in an actual program somewhere, but that it is the result of some numeric calculation about programming. For example, how many full binary trees are there with $n+1$ leaves? That's a Catalan number, and binary trees are used in programming, but I can't for the life of me figure out how one would use that information *in* a program. Rather, it is a result about programs in general, not used in a particular program.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Catalan numbers helps a lot in competitive programming puzzles. Helped me in this http://www.codechef.com/EXBT2013/problems/EXEBIT05  So, I just wanted to know all its applications wrt programming.

Comment: But who told you there were useful? Useful in coding challenges is one thing, because then you often are asked to count combinatorial sets, which is essentially what Catalan numbers do. Basically, these sorts of programming challenges are often math challenges. Why do you think they are actually helpful in real programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catalan numbers are used in stack-sortable permutations. 
Refer [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).

Comment: Thanks! that was a power pack..

Answer (score 0):

Catalan numbers count not only permutations sortable through 1 stack (see the accepted answer), but also permutations sortable through 2 parallel queues.